# Deleting files from an AIX system

Tags: shell, delete-file, aix

We have an AIX system, which gets files on a daily basis, so we manually delete the previous days files manually. Is it possible to write a script which will take the files 15 or 20 days before today and delete the files from the folder?

Comment: will this work: http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/ubuntu/delete-files-older-than-x-days-on-linux/

Comment: But is it possible for me to put this command on a batch file and run the file every week?

Comment: AIX is just System V with some BSD additions, so I would expect you to be able to add it as a cronjob without any problems (it's been over a decade since I last touched an AIX machine though..)

Answer (score 1):

If you can/may install GNU!find, them it's simple, e.g.:

```
#!/bin/sh
cd /var/log/apache
gfind . -name '*log*Z' -mtime +30 -delete
```

this script is run by cron; a line from crontab:

```
02 23 1 * * /root/cmd/httpd.logdelete >/dev/null 2>&1
```

Edit: 
-mdays + means files of which last modification date is earlier than now-
-delete means deleting the files that match the criteria

Comment: Could you please also explain the parameters in the commands above

Answer (score 1):

Or you can use native AIX find command:

```
find /dir/to/files -type f -mtime +15 -exec rm {} \;
```

where:
 `-type f`   - Find only files, not directories
 `-mtime +15` - Find files, that modification time more then 15 days
 `-exec rm {} \;` - Run command rm on each matched file
You can run this command with `-exec ls -l {} \;` for testing, that found files correspond to your criteria.